# Set Limit on Words and call new Class on the words limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, limit

I had a problem with setting the limit for the description. 
How to make the ( Read More ) appear when the description total words exceed more than the height of the div? and set the description not more than the div height?

```css
.article-detail {
  height: 160px;
}
```

```html
<div class="article-detail">
 <span> 
    The potential use cases for Blockchain spans across multiple industries and goes far beyond     just Bitcoin. Financial services, Healthcare, Audit among many others; find your industry       and we will transition you through Blockchain… ( Read more )
  </span>
</div>
```

**EDIT** I tried to make "read more" appear when the row of the text pass more than 5 row and will be hidden when the row of the text below 5. Any Idea?

```js
document.getElementById('read-more').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var text = document.querySelector('.bc-testing-detail');
  text.style.height = 'auto';
  text.style.display = 'inline';
  this.style.display = 'none'; //Hide the 'read more' link
});
```

```css
.article-detail {
  height: 160px;
}

.bc-testing-detail {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 5.7em;
}
```

```html
<div class="article-detail">
  <span class="bc-testing-detail"> 
    The potential use cases for Blockchain spans across multiple industries and goes far beyond     just Bitcoin. Financial services, Healthcare, Audit among many others; find your industry       and we will transition you through Blockchain
  </span>
  <a id="read-more" href="#"> ( Read More ) </a>
</div>
```

Comment: did you have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28225717/how-to-make-read-more-option-with-html-css

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make read more option with html/CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28225717/how-to-make-read-more-option-with-html-css)

Answer (score 1):

You need to display your `span` as block and set it's height to the number of displayed lines x the line height and its `overflow` to `hidden`.

Now convert the "read more" to a link and move it outside the `span`. Add a click event listener to it, which sets the `span` back to auto height and inline display.

**Edit** To only show the "read more" link when the text is bigger than the box, you need to compare the visible height `clientHeight` to the total (visible and invisible) height `scrollHeight`. The only problem is that there is always a small difference between them due to pixel calculation, so you can check of the difference is too small (say less than 10) and hide the "read more" button.

```js
(function() {
  var more = document.getElementById('read-more');

  more.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var text = document.querySelector('.article-detail span');
    text.style.height = 'auto';
    text.style.display = 'inline';
    this.style.display = 'none'; //Hide the 'read more' link
  });

  var text = document.querySelector('.article-detail span');
  if (text.scrollHeight - text.clientHeight < 10)
    more.click();
})();
```

```css
.article-detail span {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 2.2em; //Show 2 lines
  line-height: 1.1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="article-detail">
  <span>The potential use cases for Blockchain spans across multiple industries and goes far beyond     just Bitcoin. Financial services, Healthcare, Audit among many others; find your industry       and we will transition you through Blockchain. The potential use cases for Blockchain spans across multiple industries and goes far beyond     just Bitcoin. Financial services, Healthcare, Audit among many others; find your industry       and we will transition you through Blockchain</span>
  <a id="read-more" href="#">( Read more )</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Aweomse, Somehow works but still something missing, I set they total row to be 5 rows. And the read more will be appear if the total of the paragraph more than 5. When I make it less to 2 rows, the read more still there, how to adjust that?

Comment: I did, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: I did the changes. That's what the exact code that I put on mine.